# I want to use select2 in my Dropdown list. Here's my code. But it doesn't work. Do I need to write something in .cs file?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, jquery-select2, dropdown

```
<link href="Content/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=ddlCName.ClientID%>").select2({
            placeholder: "Choose One",
            allowClear: true

      });

  });

</script>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCName" CssClass="form-control input-sm" runat="server" Height="33px" Width="250px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CName" DataValueField="CName">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CName] FROM [CustomerRegister] ORDER BY [CName]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What *does* it do?  Is there an error on the browser's development console?  Did you load the JavaScript library for Select2?  For jQuery?  Is the expected client-side ID emitted to the JavaScript code?  Does the JavaScript code execute at all?  Does the jQuery selector find the target element?  What happens?

Comment: It doesn't work mean it doesn't appear "Choose One" placeholder in the DropDownList. But it doesn't occur error on the browser's development console. To be honest, I don't know too much. I just follow these steps (https://c-sharplibrary.blogspot.com/2017/08/create-select-2-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-c.html). I just try to get data from the SqlDataSource. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Can you do the following?:  (1) Include jQuery and Select2 JavaScript libraries in your example.  (2) Replace the server-side code in your example with the resulting client-side code.  This should make your example runnable as-is, which would demonstrate the problem more completely.